# Simple Google Cloud DataFlow ETL, from xls to db to xls

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I need to develop a brand new little system which will take the data from a few uploaded xls files with a few million rows, put it in a relational DB and then later it can be queried to output another xls file.
It has be to on Google Cloud, so I was thinking of using Google Cloud Dataflow. Is Dataflow the right tool? Where should I start to get familiar with it and how to do what I mentioned above? What's the recommended programming language? Somebody recommended using Python because they thought it would be more light weight than Java, but is that the case?

Also I would like to know about the costs, considering the process of extracting and transforming the data into the DB can be done once or twice a day and generating the xls output would be done as many times as a necessary (20 to 30 times a day)

Tbanks!

Answer (score 1):

This could be done in Dataflow, though I'm not sure what to suggest for processing the xls file format. It's a binary format isn't it? It may be easier to save as csv files if that's possible.

For CSV text files you could use [TextIO](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/text-io), which processes one line of the file at a time. Store your files in GCS and setup a pipeline to read them row by row with TextIO. Then use a custom ParDo to process each row and parse it. Then pass it off to BigQueryIO to write it to a table.

If you want to use xls files, then you may need to use a [custom source](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io) and call a library to parse the xls file.

You may wish to store your data in BigQuery. You can use [BigQueryIO](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/bigquery-io) for this.

Java is generally a little bit faster, but the amount of data you want to process doesn't seem very large. So using Python would be find if you prefer this, I would not expect a significant difference in this case.

Comment: I was actually thinking of using Google Cloud SQL since the spreadsheets look like relational tables. Gotta a question for you: files would only be uploaded to be processed by dataflow, but after they data is in the DB, they are no longer required. In that case, is Storage still required?, is there any other choice?

Comment: The files stored in GCS? Yes once you've processed them and put them in the DB you won't need them anymore, and can interact with your DB.

You can feel free to delete them after you have successfully finished running your pipeline and verified you have the output. Some users keep these files around if they want to rerun the pipeline some special reason.

If you want to process it again in Dataflow, you will need to run a pipeline that reads from CloudSQL. But there is much more support for reading from BigQuery today in the dataflow SDK. Beam has a JDBCIO source for sql but not dataflow.